# ROS/ROS2 mapping and path following with skid-steering robot and Velodyne 3D laser

Tags: navigation, gmapping, move-base, path-planning, velodyne

I built a skid-steering robot and I would like to implement a path-following application.
I would like to use the Velodyne to create the map and then specify a path on it to be followed by the robot.

I would like to know if there is some project or stack that I can use to start with.
Years ago, I used a Sick LMS111 with gmapping to create a 2D map and then I used move_base to make the robot moves. However, I'm pretty sure that now there are some other advanced tools.

I can also add RGBD cameras if it is needed.

Can you suggest me some solutions, please?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Linorobot2 github repo. I had success with just such a robot as you describe using that software.

https://github.com/linorobot/linorobot2

He has a repo called "hardware" that you'll also need.

Nav2 has more advanced tools, as you suggest.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your suggestion. Have you tried it with a real robot or just in simulation? Velodyne is already enough to run the navigation, or did you also have to use encoders and IMU?

Comment: Yes, I used IMU and encoders. But the IMU isn't so important with some robots. Juan has only one of the ekf inputs enabled from the IMU. His robot works very well! I did both sim and real robot.

Comment: So, you have used IMU+encoders+2D laser? I will try to study the code of linorobot2 to understand how I can integrate it for my robot.